# How to provide an overload for the stream output operator << for a template 'using' type alias?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Does anybody know why this does not compile and how to fix it? Somehow the compiler cannot find the correct template instantiation for the stream operator, but I don't understand why.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
using Row = std::array<int, N>;

template <int N>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Row<N>& mc) {
    for (auto i : mc)
        o << i << " ";
    return o;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Row<4> row {};
    std::cout << row << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know why this does not compile and how to fix it?

Yes: the problem is that you declare `Row` as receiving an `int`

```
template <int N>
using Row = std::array<int, N>;
```

and try to intercept it's size in the operator as an `int` when `std::array` receive (for second argument) a `std::size_t`.

So your `Row<4>` (that is `std::array<int, 4u>` where `4u` is a `std::size_t`) doesn't matches your operator because the operator looks for a `std::array<int, N>` where `N` is an `int`.

Fix: define `Row` as receiving a `std::size_t` (optional, just for clarity) and deduce a `std::size_t` in the operator (mandatory).

```
template <std::size_t N> // <--- you have to intercept a std::size_t
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Row<N>& mc) {
    for (auto i : mc)
        o << i << " ";
    return o;
}
```

Alternative C++17 fix: intercept the operator size as `auto`

```
template <auto N> // <--- auto can intercept a std::size_t
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const Row<N>& mc) {
    for (auto i : mc)
        o << i << " ";
    return o;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to say that [using `size_t` works](https://ideone.com/j9SAwJ) but you beat me to it.

Comment: Great! out of curisotiy: calling `operator<<<4>(std::cout, row) << std::endl;` – no template deduction involved – works.

Comment: @眠りネロク - exactly: because no deduction is involved.